# Grabbing a hash from a suspected sqllite3 database file

Tags: passwords, databases, password-cracking, forensics, hashcat

I have a .db file that is encrypted when opened with DB Browser for SQLite as it asks for a password which is not known. I am trying to obtain the hash and hash type for this file as I know it has been made using SQLCipher.

Research of how SQLCipher works show's that an AES 256 bit encryption has been applied to the file. I would like to run this file through the password cracking software "hashcat" but without knowing the hash type, I cannot perform this action.

Is there anyway to retrieve the hash type from the given file so I can perform a dictionary attack using hashcat?

Comment: What makes you think there's a hash involved? You said it yourself, that it appears to be symmetrically encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

AES 256 is a form of encryption, two way. Hashes are one way.

It sounds to me like the database is encrypted with AES 256 and when decrypted (using a password/passphrase) it will allow you to browse it. SQLCipher is a full database encryption technique. When browsing it you might come across hash values, most likely in a password column.

Hashcat is for hashes, it takes the hash (which is one way) and tries to find a collission (or uses other smart tricks) to determine what password would lead to that hash.

1: Decrypt the database
2: Find the hashes
3: Let loose the hashcat! (and try to determine the hash type)

Comment: This is the next step after grabbing the hash of the password that was used to encrypt the database and cracking it using hashcat. I cannot find a way to grab the hash of the password that was used to encrypt this database file.